# Excel VBA AutoFilter Array error

Tags: arrays, excel, autofilter, vba

My data is like follows:

Name    Value   Flag

Alice   5       BUYBACK

Bob     8       Jump

Dan     9

Alice   1

Alice   6       Jump

Dan     0       BUYBACK

Bob     8       Jump

If for any Name, in any record, in the Flag field if there is a "BUYBACK" then I want to preserve all the records associated with that name. Alice has 3 records and one of them is BUYBACK so I want to keep all of ALice's records. Dan has a buy back in one of the two so I want to keep both of Dan's records while both of Bob's records get deleted.

When I try to do it below, I get an error in my AutoFilter. The error says "Object required". I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

```
 n = 1

     Dim BBK_Array() As Variant

     For j = 1 To FinalRow

        If Cells(j, 3).Value = "BUYBACK" Then
            If n = 1 Then
                 ReDim Preserve BBK_Array(1 To n)
                 BBK_Array(n) = Cells(j, 1).Value
                 n = n + 1

            ElseIf BBK_Array(n - 1) <> Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                    ReDim Preserve BBK_Array(1 To n)
                    BBK_Array(n) = Cells(j, 1).Value
                    n = n + 1

            End If


        End If
     Next j




     ActiveWorksheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=BBK_Array(), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

EDIT:

When I did this, it worked. I don't know why:

```
     ActiveWorkbook.Activesheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=BBK_Array(), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Where is **FinalRow** established??

Comment: @Gary's Student .. earlier in the code. When I did Activeworkbook.activesheet then it worked.

Comment: OK I guess my sheet wasn't active or something. Should I delete the question? Can you tell me why activeworkbook.activesheet worked but just activesheek didn't? I wrote the macro in the same file in which the data is kept. thanks

Comment: Don't delete the question.....fix the problems as you find them.......also fix the spelling of **BuyBack** v.s. **BUYBACK**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need VBA for this? A simple Excel formula can solve your problem.

Let's say your data looks like this

[image]

All you need to do is create a 4th column and enter is formula in cell `D2`

`=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=A2)*(C:C="BuyBack"))`

Simply auto fill the formula to the last row. Now filter col `D` on `0` and delete it.

[image]

See this.

[image]

Once done, delete col `D`

**If you still want a VBA solution then record a macro and follow the above steps and simply amend it to suit your needs. It will be 9 lines of code (including the declarations)**

Here is an example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ws.Range("D2:D" & lRow).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=A2)*(C:C=""BuyBack""))"
    ws.Range("D2:D" & lRow).Value = ws.Range("D2:D" & lRow).Value

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Range("D2:D" & lRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=0"
    ws.Range("D2:D" & lRow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

    ws.Columns(4).Delete
End Sub
```

And this is the output we get after the macro is run.

[image]

Comment: This is a small portion of a very long series of data processing that I am doing. My boss wants me to create a button that will enable him to upload his monthly file and generate all kinds of stuff with one click. I am brand new to excel vba and you will see every step of the project on here as I struggle with stuff. :)

Comment: It will be approximately 10-15 lines of code (minus the declarations).

Comment: neat method though! Thanks!!

Comment: @Amatya: Amended my answer `It will be 9 lines of code (including the declarations)`

Comment: In Mathematica coding, they have 1 line coding competitions. I think you're a future champion. :)